# wifi adapter not found

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my DELL LATITUDE E6420 laptop. All packages of Ubuntu seem to be working properly including wifi for the first few days. Now when I log on it says WiFi adapter is not found, and I can't connect to the wireless network.

Comment: Hi Gerald - I know this is a simple thing but it's worth checking first: I've got a Dell E5430 and it has a small switch on the case that turns the wifi off. On a few occassions I've accidentally switched it off without realising at some point (on the E5430 the switch is quite close to the catch on the lid) and later spent ages fiddling around with the machine before realising my mistake.

Comment: A good way to check if it's a 'hardware switch' causing this is to use `rfkill list` to show if there's a hardware or software block on the wireless device. On my Dell, both the *dell-wifi* and *phy0* show as **Hard blocked: yes** when I use the physical switch on the case.

Comment: E6540 FOUND A SWITCH, clicked it to red, restarting....